# Is it acceptable to reply with a 200 response code to a Range request?

Tags: http

When a client sends a request with a [Range](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35) header, is it acceptable to just ignore that, and return a `200 OK` response with the full content?

The spec says:

> If the byte-range-set is unsatisfiable, the server SHOULD return a
>   response with a status of 416 (Requested range not satisfiable).
>   Otherwise, the server SHOULD return a response with a status of 206
>   (Partial Content) containing the satisfiable ranges of the
>   entity-body.

As I understand it, *should* implies that it's still acceptable to skip that and return a `200 OK`. Am I right?

Comment: I infer the opposite, I expect that it *must* return the specified response(s).

Comment: `A server MAY ignore the Range header.` in 14.35.2 says that a 200 is ok, since it is what you'd reply with if you did not receive the header.

Comment: No need to infer anything.  The definition of `SHOULD` is spelled out explicitly in [RFC 2119](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2119).

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Can you add this as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[§14.35.2](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35.2) of the linked spec states;

> A server MAY ignore the Range header.

In other words, a 200 with the full contents is a valid reply, since it is what you'd reply with if you did not receive the header.